# Highcharts/stock xAxis display only year

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm building some charts with highstocks.

**My data looks like:**

```
[1133308800, 1.95492806759836],
[1135987200, 2.01739233585526],
[1138665600, 2.0725059567737],
[1141084800, 1.89533596472326],
```

And my xAxis settings:

```
            xAxis: {

                labels: {
                    style: {
                        textTransform: 'uppercase',
                        color: '#a7b9c7',
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue, Helvetica',
                        fontSize: '11px'
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                minorTickLength: 0,
                tickLength: 0,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: '#3b3c40',
                    dashStyle: 'dot',
                    value: .5,
                    width: 1
                }]
            },
```

The problem is that the labels on xAxis are like *14. Jan* etc. I want to be just the year from my data.

```
    $.getJSON(name + '.json', function(data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: colors[i]
        };

        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
```

Can someone explain me how to display only the year on the xAxis?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure datetime labels by [dateTimeLabelFormats](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats)

```
{
    millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
}
```